# How to add search bar in one2many field in form view odoo 12?

Tags: jquery, python-3.x, xml, odoo-12

I just want to add a search bar in one2many field in form view. So that it will easy to search item of one2many field, just like below image.

[image]

Your answer will be appreciate.

Comment: Looking for the same. Did you find anything?